# Remove site from single Google search results

Tags: search-engines, google-search

I want to remove a specific website from a single searches results to find what I am looking for.

An example (the one that brought me here) is searching for Avery divider marker templates. The Avery website requires registration to find the templates so I want to find them elsewhere. However all results so far have come from Avery's official website.

Is there anyway I can remove this site from my results? (for only this search, I have found solutions that apply to all searches)

Comment: Websites don't count as computer software? In an increasingly web-based world that is a very old fashion idea.

Comment: For Chrome there is https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef?hl=en

Comment: This would be on-topic (and has probably been answered) at [webapps.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for `keyword another keyword -site:avery.com`

Comment: I didn't realize you could stack the `-` and `site:` operators.

Answer (score 2):

In the Google search box, you would use `-site:Avery.com`

So you would have something like `Avery Templates for <Divider Number> -site:Avery.com`

Comment: I comment on one and this one updates to be the same. lol. Now I have to take 8 minutes to decide who to give the answer credit too.

Comment: @Fr33dan Looks like grudolf answered right before me.  He wins the race :)

Comment: Weird because I was definitely reading yours (in the state without the `site:` part) when I got the message "there is a new answer to this question". Then I was typing my comment on his when yours said "this answer has been edited".

Comment: lol, I did read it wrong...his was answered after mine.  Oh well, he had less points, so let's help him get his rep up :)

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking.